# How do I add the time to the netcdf file?

Tags: r, time-series, netcdf, netcdf4

I want to create a time series in a netcdf file with 3 dimensions(lon, lat, time[unlimited]). The timeseries should be created from other netcdf-files. Each of them have only one timepoint [For Example 17856]. 
I know how to create the new netcdf-file, how to extract the data from the netcdf-file as a 2D array and the time for the data.
My problem is:
How do I put the 2D array in the netcdf-file with its correct time? How does the start and count argument in the "ncvar_put" fucntion does work?

I use the ncdf4 package and read the Tutorial on:

http://geog.uoregon.edu/bartlein/courses/geog490/week04-netCDF.html#create-and-write-a-netcdf-file and searched for an answer but I still don`t understand it. I´m still unexperienced with netcdf files.

## Example

```
e of my problem:

# data from other netcdf file
values = array(data = c(1:9)/10, dim = c(3,3))
values_2 = array(data = c(9:25)/10, dim = c(3,3))
time = 25
time_2 = 23

# set parameters
lon = 1:3
lat = 1:3


# define dimensions
# Longitude
londim = ncdim_def(name = "longitude", units = "degrees", vals = as.double(lon),
                   longname = "longitude")
# Latitude
latdim = ncdim_def(name = "latitude", units = "degrees", vals = as.double(lat),
                   longname = "latitude")
# Time
timedim = ncdim_def(name = "time", units ="days since 1582-10-15 00:00", vals = as.double(1),
                    unlim = TRUE, calendar = "gregorian")

# define variables
B01 = ncvar_def(name = "B01",
                units ="percent",
                list(londim,latdim,timedim), 
                missval = NA,
                prec="double")

# create netcdf
nc_test = nc_create("test.nc", list(B01), force_v4 = TRUE)

# Add values 
### Here is somethin missing --> How do I add the timestamp?
ncvar_put(nc_test, "B01", values, start=c(1,1,1), count=c(-1,-1,1))
ncvar_put(nc_test, "B01", values2, start=c(1,1,2), count=c(-1,-1,1))
```

When I want to extract the data I get the 3-3-2 array, but the timesteps are not correct, because I didnt add them. How do I do this?
I would like to have the  3-3-2 array and when I take the time and I want the right times in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

I add time to the netCDF file by using another method. This is the sample code for your reference.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from netCDF4 import date2num
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import os

# generate time for netCDF with 1 hour interval
utc_now = datetime.utcnow()
time_list = [utc_now + timedelta(hours=1*step) for step in range(6)]
trans_time = date2num(time_list, units="hours since 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0", calendar="gregorian") 

with Dataset(os.getcwd() + "/sample.nc", "w") as sample:
    # Create dimension for sample.nc
    time = sample.createDimension("time", None)
    lat = sample.createDimension("lat", 3)  # 3 is the latitude size in this sample
    lon = sample.createDimension("lon", 3)

    # Create variable for sample.nc
    time = sample.createVariable("time","f8",("time",))
    lat = sample.createVariable("lat","f4",("lat",))
    lon = sample.createVariable("lon","f4",("lon",))

    time[:] = trans_time

    variable_with_time = sample.createVariable("variable_with_time", "f4", ("time", "lat", "lon"))

    for key, value in sample.variables.items():
        print(key)
        print(value)
        print("*"*70)
```

Output:

```
time
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 time(time)
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (6,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used
**********************************************************************
lat
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 lat(lat)
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (3,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used
**********************************************************************
lon
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 lon(lon)
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (3,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used
**********************************************************************
variable_with_time
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 variable_with_time(time, lat, lon)
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (6, 3, 3)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used
**********************************************************************
```

You may notice that, time is placed as the first dimension. For detailed information, this is the [link](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html#netCDF4.Dataset.createVariable) to the document that I referenced.